# When I use Automapper for my model. model's Id is changing

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, automapper, .net-5

This is my first question so I am very nervous :) You can see the question below :

This is my mapping profile

```
CreateMap<UpdateUserVM, AppUser>().ForAllMembers(a => a.UseDestinationValue());
```

My Viewmodel has not Id's property. In the same time I am using IdentityFramework for my project.

Here are the my method. When I use this method my models id is changing. If  you can help me  I will be very happy :) Thanks

```
public async Task<object> UpdateUser(UpdateUserVM updateUserVM, string id)
{
    AppUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    user = mapper.Map<AppUser>(updateUserVM);
    var result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    string msg = string.Empty;
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            msg += $"{error.Code} - {error.Description}\n";
        }
        return msg;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In .Net Core 6 Api, how to map only the values that exist in the DTO uisng AutoMapper 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73429751/in-net-core-6-api-how-to-map-only-the-values-that-exist-in-the-dto-uisng-autom)

Comment: @Progman not the best answer in your link. No need to manually update properties when AutoMapper can do that for us. And... it's slightly different question. Here we don't have `Id` on view-model.

Comment: @Nenad There are other answers in that question, including https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432823/286934 where I explain to use the `Map()` overload with the second parameter.

Comment: @Progman It's different question. And the best answer would be to set mapping the `Id` on destination to "ignore". Writing `Id = id` manually to both source and destination is not necessary. Perhaps I should answer that question correctly (from AutoMapper perspective) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a different `Map` method overload that is specifically used to update properties on existing destination object:

```
mapper.Map(updateUserVM, user);
```

So, in your sample code it would be:

```cs
public async Task<object> UpdateUser(UpdateUserVM updateUserVM, string id)
{
    AppUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    mapper.Map(updateUserVM, user); // use different `Map` overload
    var result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    string msg = string.Empty;
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            msg += $"{error.Code} - {error.Description}\n";
        }
        return msg;
    }
    return true;
}
```